# Are objects stored on the stack?

Tags: c++

Since objects are constructed via a hidden function, as opposed to primitive types, it makes perfect sense scoping variables for performance in C++, whereas in C99 it doesn't.

My question is: are the objects stored on the stack *anyway*?

Comment: This is hard to tell what's being asked here. Could you please try rephrasing?

Comment: Without sarcasm, what's being asked ends with a question mark. The first part illustrates how I got to ask it.

Comment: Last i checked, C++ had no concept of stack vs heap.  You could have a conforming C++ compiler that didn't touch the stack at all.  At the very *very* least, that means that the standards don't specify anything about what gets stored on the stack.

Comment: What do you mean in the first sentence?

Comment: I think the first part means that objects are created through a constructor whereas primitive types are not. Not sure about the second sentence.

Comment: @catfish Without a comprehensive lesson on English, the word "anyway" implies the action of objects being stored on the stack happens despite *something else* but your previous sentence doesn't make clear what *something else* you are referring to.

Answer (score 3):

In standard C++ there is no such thing as a stack. The standard only differentiates between the different lifetimes of objects. In that case a variable declared as `T t;` is said to have automatic storage duration, which means it life-time ends with the end of it's surrounding scope. Most (all?) compilers implement this through a stack. It is a reasonable assumption that all objects created that way actually live on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

[Automatically allocated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_memory_allocation) [local] objects are located on automatic memory area ["stack"] while [dynamically allocated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#Dynamic_memory_allocation) objects are located in dynamic memory area ["heap"].

As a rule of thumb: in C++, everyting that is not using `new` or `malloc` is automatically allocated.

**EDIT:** Note that I use "stack" and "heap" with double quotes since the standard [AFAIK] does not specify how the data is managed in these areas, but [again AFAIK], compilers indeed tend to use stack for automatic area and heap for dynamic area.

Comment: If you read the article you linked for statically allocated, you'll see the term does not apply to items on the stack. Stack items are 'automatically allocated'. Your second sentence is therefore not correct.

Comment: @SteveFallows: You are correct. I am not a native english speaker and I mixed up terms. I editted the answer. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: What is a static area and a dynamic area? It is really about the life-time of single objects, not areas. But that is really just terminology bashing.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you mean in your first sentence, but: yes, objects in local variables are generally stored on the stack.